# Why doesn't the incremental function work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just want to make an operation available two times.
For example:

I press 5 on the keyboard and Object1 is instantiated but, at the same time, the counter is increased by one.
After this, I press 5 again, the Object1 is instantiated again, the counter is increased by one again.
So, this time, if  I try to press 5 for a third time, nothing happens.

Should be easy right? That's what I thought and I still think that it should be this easy but, every time i press 5, the Object1 is instantiated and the counter doesn't increase.
To be more specific, the counter increase for a moment and after that instant, it resets to 0.

```
public class Placement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Object1;
    private int count = 0;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(count);
        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha5)) && count < 2)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            Instantiate(Object1, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            this.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I simplified the code just to get straight to the point.
Through the console (debug) I saw that the count is automatically reset to 0 at each cycle...

Comment: Are you sure that it's the same `Placement` object all the time? If `count` gets "reset" then it sounds like you're creating new `Placement` objects.

Comment: Do you only have a single `Placement` object instance or is that being re-created. You need to show your loop/cycle logic, that is where the key to this will be

Comment: If `Instantiate` creates a new instance on Object1 class each time the key is pressed then it's counter will be initialised to zero each time. You will have two `Object1` instances but only be referencing one.

Comment: Also, you never actually instantiate or create the object for `object1`. [The `Instantiate` function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) will *clone* the (what we can see) uninitialized object `object1` and return a reference to the cloned object.

Comment: if you see the log increase and then be `0` again I would suspect that the thing you instantiate (`Object1`) has this `Placement` component attached as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code logic, you will disable the Object after pressing 5. You probably want to disable it after 2 presses.

```
if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha5)) && count < 2)
{
    count = count + 1;
    Instantiate(Object1, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    if(count >= 2) {
        this.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The reason it appears, that your counter doesn't increase at all is this: You log `count` but then disable it after pressing 5, so no more logs will happen in `Update()`.

Tip: You could make `count` public or use `[Serializable]`, OR use the debug-inspector view to see the actual value of count, instead of relying on the Debug.Log.

**edit**: If Object1 has the `Placement` script attached, you are creating more and more scripts (with a `count` variable each).

It's best to have a manager object that instantiates other objects.
But you can also remove/disable the script on the instantiated objects like this:

```
if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha5)) && count < 2)
{
    count = count + 1;
    GameObject newObj = Instantiate(Object1, transform.position, transform.rotation);


    newObj.getComponent<Placement>().enabled = false; // this disables the script

    // (optional) Destroy(newObj.getComponent<Placement>()); // this removes the script
    

    if(count >= 2) {
        this.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought too the problem could be that but I need to leave it as it was in my code.
If I put the other condition(as you wrote), Unity creates more instantiated objects in the same position and the scenes "slows down".

Comment: So what is "Object1" that you are instantiating? If the "Placement" script is attached to that, the newly instantiated objects will too instantiate objects whenever you press 5...

Comment: Well you log the value of `count` every frame, so if you have multiple objects with the `Placement` component, your console will be flooded with 0's and the increased counts may be overlooked. You could make count `static` so it acts like a global count for every Placement object, but I'm sure the actual problem is somewhere else.

Comment: That's what I think. You could remove the script or disable it after instantiating (before the first `Update` of the new object would be called. I will update my answer.

Comment: In the end, I placed an EmptyGameObject in the scene used as an universal counter(I created a simple script called Counter.cs) and in the original script I just wrote this to get my variable in the script:      
count = FindObjectOfType<Counter>();

Comment: That is not recommended, FindObjectOfType<> is considered "slow" and will get slower when your scenes grow. A static variable may work, Make `static int count = 0;` and simply access it by `Counter.count` from anywhere, no reference needed. If you keep using FindObjectOfType<>, please do that in `Start()` once and create a reference variable that you reuse, opposed to calling `Find` every frame.